# set properties by vm-option in tomcat (local)

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have some question.

Before format My intellij is work very well.
I manage some value for multiple environment and control by some properties file.

Here is some sample.
I have some file for properties like this.

`production.properties`
`test.properties`
`test-remote.properties`

And my tomcat configuration (of course VM options) set like this.
`... -Drun.mode=test ...`

And here is my `root-context.xml`.

```
...

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:${run.mode}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
...
```

Before format, as i say, if change the tomcat's vmoption -Drun.mode=SOMETHING, that works. but after format, there is only work `test` properties.

have you guys any idea about it? I can't imagine even how can i fix it.

Very interesting point is that. test is work well.
But there is not hardcoding for just only use `test.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different that tomcat's version.

usually i use 8.5.x and after format i used 9.0.x and there have some ClassNotFound Exception.

After change to use tomcat 8.5.x problem is gone.

But have to figure out why 9.0.x is not running for Properties file select by VM options.